# Get variables names from string expression in R (Renjin)

Tags: java, r, parsing, eval, renjin

I'm using Renjin to evaluate R formulas from my Java program. Basically the user is typing an R formula in a text field, and I want R/Renjin to do the parsing for me, and return a list of the variables in that expression. Say if the user inputs *a*b*, I want `["a", "b"]` as the result.

I looked at the `RParser.parse()` method on the Java part. But when I call then `RParser.getResult()` I get a `SEXP` object from which I didn't find a way to get the variables names.

On the R side, I looked at `parse(text="a*b")`. I can `eval()` it, but I didn't find a way to get the names either.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

From R, it's possible to achieve this with:

```
> d = getParseData(parse(text="a*b"))
> d$text[which(d$token=="SYMBOL")]
[1] "a" "b"
```

The problem is, when I run it with Renjin, I get `Exception in thread "main" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: getParseData() is not currently supported by Renjin`.

Still looking…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `all.vars` and `all.names` will return all the names in a formula. The difference is that `all.names` also includes function names, while `all.vars` excludes them.

```
> f <- y ~ a + sin(b)
> f
y ~ a + sin(b)

> all.vars(f)
[1] "y" "a" "b"

> all.names(f)
[1] "~"   "y"   "+"   "a"   "sin" "b"
```

I don't know if Renjin supports these, but they're fairly basic.